# How to set up the publish and prompt to front end settings in feed importer?

Tags: feeds

I have a feed importer which is attach to the "feed source" content type. This feed importer create nodes of type "Blog". I want when I want to create a feed source content and select the publish in the publish settings the newly created blogs should also be published. But if while creating the feed source content I unchecked the publish in the publish settings the the newly created blogs should also be unpublished. Same is for prompt to front end.

How can I achieve this functionality through feed importer?

Comment: You can set published for being unpublished from content type edit.

Comment: No, I want it in feed importer. I want to add such a functionality in the feed importer when While creating the feed source content when I select publish then the newly created blogs should also be published and when I uncheck the publish in the feed source content then newly created blogs should also be unpublished.